# How to get GLFW Window Id?

Tags: c++, gstreamer, glfw

I wish to render gstreamer video stream on glfw window. According to gstreamer overlay design if you give related winId it will render it. Like Qt example:

```
  QWidget window;
  window.resize(320, 240);
  window.show();

  WId xwinid = window.winId();
  gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle (GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY (sink), xwinid);
```

But I couldn't find a winId with GLFW.

```
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(...);
```

It has a window structure type but that's all. Is there a way to get it's Id or should I follow another way for glfw ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For GLFW 3, just take a look at the documentation, it should give you the [answer](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__native.html), but this is not cross platform and maybe risky as the doc says:

**By using the native access functions you assert that you know what you're doing and how to fix problems caused by using them. If you don't, you shouldn't be using them**:

For Windows, if you want the Win32 Handle of the window:

1) define `GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_WIN32`

2) include glfw3native.h

3) use `HWND glfwGetWin32Window (GLFWwindow *window)`

You can find equivalents for X11 and Cocoa as well...

Edit: 
For X11, if you want the Window object:

1) define `GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_X11`

2) include glfw3native.h

3) use `Window glfwGetX11Window (GLFWwindow *window)`

Comment: Thanks. My issue was with X11 but after searching a while I moved to SDL2 which has a inner solution.